# What happens while launching /bin/sh?

Tags: shell, linux-kernel

Suspecting /bin/sh launching taking considerable boot ticks on my embedded linux kit.
In the kernel, /bin/sh being launched from kernel_init().

1. Will it look for start-up scripts?
2. If so, what would be the name of the scripts?
3. How is possible to measure the boot-up time of /bin/sh?

Comment: What kind of shell is your /bin/sh ?

Comment: `man sh` should provide you with answers to your first two questions for your specific system.

Answer (score 0):

To measure the run-time of a command, you can prefix it with the time command. In this case

```
time /bin/sh -c exit
```

would be useful for you. It starts /bin/sh, which then immediately runs the exit command, so the time you will get is the startup time plus the termination time of sh. Alternatively, you might be interested in the strace command, which prints all the system calls initiated by the program it runs. This is a way to guess if sh tries to open any files, through examinig stat and/or open calls. strace works in the same way as time. I hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: On some systems, `/bin/sh` links to a more complex shell (e.g. on Linux, /bin/sh -> bash), so the first statement is incorrect.

Comment: True... My bad I guessed it's such a minimal system that it's not the case.